# 0x Protocol - Can I use for selling an NFT and get back an ERC-20 token example BUSD on BSC?

Tags: solidity, web3js, bsc, 0x, solidity-0.8.x

I'm using [0x Protocol](https://www.0x.org) for my project. And I want to use BUSD as asset that taker must pay to maker.
In 0x's document describes we can use native token BNB or WBNB, but not clear about if we can use another ERC-20 token ex: BUSD ... or not ?
Can I do that ?
I tried to use BUSD smart contract as taker's asset data, but it's not working.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using either [ERC721Orders.sol](https://docs.0x.org/protocol/docs/exchange-proxy/features/erc721orders) or [ERC1155Orders.sol](https://docs.0x.org/protocol/docs/exchange-proxy/features/erc1155orders), you should be able to buy or sell a particular NFT for some amount of ERC20 token.

Can you share a code snippet of how you've set up the transfer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use. I'm using NftSwapSdk v3. I can do bundle swap.
ERC721 + ERC1155 + ERC20 TO ERC721 + ERC1155 + ERC20
I can use weth, ape, usdc.

```
const oToken: SwappableAsset = {
   tokenAddress: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
   type: 'ERC20',
   amount: ethers.utils.parseEther('0.01').toString()
}
const order = NftSwapSdk.buildOrder(
   makerAssets,
   [oToken],
   makerAddress,
   config
)
```